# Itō process and filtrations

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

Let $X_t$ be an Itō process related to a Brownian motion $B_t$

$$ X_t = \int_0^t a(t) \text{d}B_t $$

where $a(t)$ is a process which is adapted to the natural filtration
of $B_t$, say $\mathcal{B}_t$.

Considering the natural filtration $\mathcal{X}_t$  of the process $X_t$, what simple (simple-to-prove) conditions warrant that the filtrations
$\mathcal{X}_t$ and $\mathcal{B}_t$ are identical? For instance if
$a(t)$ is a non-random positive function, this seems to be true.

Comment: Maybe if you can write $B_t=\int_0^t b(s)dX_s$ for a suitable process $b$ $\mathcal{X}_t$-adapted ?

Comment: $b(s):= 1/a(s)$ seems the only choice. But is-it $\mathcal{X}_t$-adpated?

Comment: I think you know what to look for now

Comment: may be you should start with simple processes